# Container View Controller delegate assignment

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a parent view controller with two embedded controllers which I linked up using Storyboard. I am trying to allow communication among the ViewControllers by using delegates.

The problem is, I am stuck at trying to assign the delegate because I dont have a reference of my `ChildViewController` in the parent. Basically, I am looking for somewhere in `ParentViewController.m` to insert the code

```
ChildViewController.delegate = self;
```

I tried creating `IBOutlets` for each of the ChildViewControllers but I cant seem to assign them properly in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. In code you can get a reference to the child view controllers with self.childViewControllers, which gives you an array of all the children. The preferred way, is probably to use prepareForSegue:sender:. This will be called when the parent controller is instantiated, and you can get a reference to the child with segue.destinationViewController. Give each of the embed segues identifiers so you can know which segue is calling prepareForSegue. Someething like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *topController;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIViewController *bottomController;
@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"topEmbed"]) {
        self.topController = segue.destinationViewController;
    }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"bottomEmbed"]){
        self.bottomController = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect! Thanks! I guess the lesson for me here was that the code and storyboard works very closely together to achieve the same objective. It was childish of me to think that everything could have been done via Storyboard.